# Regular expression replace won't evalute the existing variable, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what I am trying to do -

1) Search a pattern in the string. say - `[MY-ELEMENT-XYZ]`

2) Replace the pattern with the variable. - `val.XYZ` (val is an object, XYZ is the first regex group)

3) I am expecting this to be replaced with object value I have already. But this becomes undefined.

For example -

```
 val = {ID: "15452", NAME: "Home", shorturl: "", DATE: "20/08/2014", meta: ""…}

 myHtml = <body>[MY-ELEMENT-ID]<div>[MY-ELEMENT-NAME]</div></body>

 Myreplace = myHtml.replace(/\[MY-ELEMENT-(\w+)\]/gi, **val.$1**);
```

Here `val.$1` should be replaced by `val.ID`, `val.NAME` and should come up with there value, But it's returning undefined.

Any clues ?

Comment: `replace` takes a callback; do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback function:

```
Myreplace = myHtml.replace(/\[MY-ELEMENT-(\w+)\]/gi, function(match, capture1) {
    return val[capture1];
});
```